# OpenVPN gateway does not reply on IPv6 ping, but does forward package

Tags: ipv6, policy-routing

I am trying to debug my IPv6 network and ran into an issue that I can't understand.

I am using OpenVPN as my VPN server and here is a short diagram of the setup:

[image: IPv6 network with dual homed VPN server]
All packages are dropped, when I try to ping from VPN Client (`2001:470:7875:1::2`) to VPN Server (`2001:470:7875:1::1`), but here is the curious thing:

I can ping any *other* host over IPv6 (like Google) or any other VPN client connecting to the same VPN server over IPv6.

I can also ping my VPN server on its native IPv6 interface (`ens3`). It is only the VPN server interface (`tun0`) that does not respond when pinged directly.

Therefore I am wondering what is going on?

Since I have two IPv6 links to the IPv6 version of internet I have todo policy based routing. The rules are pretty simple.

- Only IPv6 packages that *originates from VPN server* itself are allowed to be sent over the native IPv6 link.
- *All other IPv6 packages* has to be handled by the Hurricane Electric IPv6 tunnel.

This leads my to the following routing table on the VPN server:

The command `ip -6 rule show` has the following setup:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32000:  from 2001:470:7875::/48 lookup openvpn
32766:  from all lookup main
```

Table `local`:

```
local ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast 2001:470:1f14:2c7:: dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2001:470:1f14:2c7::2 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast 2001:470:7875:1:: dev tun0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2001:470:7875:1::1 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast 2a01:xxx:xxxx:: dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a01:xxx:xxxx:xxx::1 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev tun0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast fe80:: dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::95d2:9e6b dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::5054:ff:fe66:f97f dev ens3 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::af96:f1e3:dbf3:96a7 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev ens3 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev tun0 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev he-ipv6 metric 256 pref medium
```

Table `main`:

```
local ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:470:1f14:2c7::/64 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:470:7875:1::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
unreachable 2001:470:7875::/48 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
2xxx:xxx:xxxx::/48 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ens3 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2a01:xxx:xxxx::1 dev ens3 metric 1024 pref medium
```

Table `openvpn`:

```
unreachable 2001:470:7875::/48 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
default via 2001:470:1f14:2c7::1 dev he-ipv6 metric 1024 pref medium
```

Is there anybody who can clue me in? :-)

---

**A quick recap on the unreachable lines in routing table**

```
2001:470:1f14:2c7::/64 dev he-ipv6 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:470:7875:1::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
unreachable 2001:470:7875::/48 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
```

The range of `2001:470:7875::/48` is from `2001:470:7875:0:0:0:0:0` to `2001:470:7875:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`.

I have assigned the subnet `2001:470:7875:1::/64` to the VPN tunnel.

- `2001:470:7875:1::/64` is part of the `2001:470:7875::/48` subnet, which can leads to a conflict in the routing table.
- `2001:470:1f14:2c7::/64` is **not** a part of the `2001:470:7875::/48` subnet and therefore does not conflict with routing table.

No other IP range is in use, but will be at a undetermined later date.

Keeping in mind longest prefix wins gives us the following behaviour:

- Any IP packages for `2001:470:1f14:2c7::/64` subnet will be handled by he-ipv6 interface.
- Any IP packages for `2001:470:7875:1::/64` subnet will be handled by tun0 interface.
- All **other** IP packages for 2001:470:7875::/48 subnet will be replied back with unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

After more digging I found out my setup could be refined a bit, though I am not entirely convinced that I have covered all my bases.

Anyway `ip -6 rule show` could be tweaked a bit.

the line:

```
32000:  from 2001:470:7875::/48 lookup openvpn
```

Was generated by the following command:

```
ip -6 rule add priority 32000 from 2001:470:7875::/48 table openvpn
```

This could be simplified to:

```
ip -6 rule add priority 32000 iif tun0 to 2000::/3 table openvpn
```

What this means is basically all IPv6 based traffic have to lookup the table `openvpn` **if and only if traffic originates from VPN link** and destination address belongs to the `2003::/3`, which is basically the whole official IPv6 Internet - excluding local addresses like fe80::/10 and fc::/7.

The end result is that IPv6 traffic from my VPN link is always forwarded over the Hurricane Electric link.

Things to remember. Whenever I add a new subnet from my pool of available adresses in the  `2001:470:7875::/48` range I have to make two entries.

- One in the table `main`, which tells how to forward the package from VPN server the new subnet.
- On in the table `openvpn`, which tells how the VPN clients can get to the new subnet. This is typically when having site-to-site traffic from one client to another client over the VPN link.

In any case: Ping works now and I can still ping Google over IPv6.

The command `ip -6 rule show` now gives the following output:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32000:  from all to 2000::/3 iif tun0 lookup openvpn
32766:  from all lookup main
```

Everything else is as-is from the initial question.

Traceroute was a bit tricky, but it works as long as is done with ICMP Echo packages.

Running the command `traceroute -6 -I google.com` on my VPN client gave the following trace:

```
traceroute to google.com (2a00:1450:400e:80b::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2001:470:7875:1::1 (2001:470:7875:1::1)  16.868 ms  37.912 ms  37.847 ms
 2  tunnel547738.tunnel.tserv11.ams1.ipv6.he.net (2001:470:1f14:2c7::1)  37.777 ms  37.710 ms  37.647 ms
 3  10ge11-20.core1.ams1.he.net (2001:470:0:7d::1)  37.575 ms  37.509 ms  37.443 ms
 4  amsix-router.google.com (2001:7f8:1::a501:5169:1)  37.453 ms  52.425 ms  52.392 ms
 5  2001:4860:0:f8d::1 (2001:4860:0:f8d::1)  52.323 ms  52.259 ms  52.189 ms
 6  2001:4860:0:1::219f (2001:4860:0:1::219f)  36.456 ms  25.560 ms  18.169 ms
 7  ams17s01-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400e:80b::200e)  34.566 ms  34.502 ms  34.435 ms
```